# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'twinx'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, twinx

I am trying to plot histograms with two y axes.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(12, 8))
ax2 = ax.twinx()
```

but this line `(ax2 = ax.twinx())` results in error:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'twinx'
```

Comment: ax is a list/array of axes,  not a single axis object.

Comment: When `nrows` or `ncols` are larger than `1`, `plt.subplots(...)` creates a numpy array of axes.  You can use `ax2 = ax[0,0].twinx() ` in the given code.  The [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) suggest calling the variable `axs` in that case. Or `fig, ((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(....)`